# How to convert the weights to 1D array?

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, arraylist, numpy-ndarray

I have the following weights of my keras model.

```
x_train_mnist = np.expand_dims(x_train_mnist, axis=-1)     
x_train_mnist = np.repeat(x_train_mnist, 3, axis=-1)        

x_train_mnist = x_train_mnist.astype('float32') / 255

x_train_mnist = tf.image.resize(x_train_mnist, [75,75]) 

x_test_mnist = np.expand_dims(x_test_mnist, axis=-1)

x_test_mnist = np.repeat(x_test_mnist, 3, axis=-1)         


x_test_mnist = x_test_mnist.astype('float32') / 255

x_test_mnist = tf.image.resize(x_test_mnist, [75,75])

model=tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
 include_top=True,
    pooling=None,
    classes=10,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(75,75,3)
)
```

Now the weights of the model is a list of lists as can be observed from the following snippet

```
weights=model.weights
print(type(weights))
weights_np=np.array(weights)
print(type(weights_np))
weights_npfloat_32=np.float32(weights_np)
print(weights_np.size)
```

**Output**

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
/tmp/ipykernel_3796671/1208296518.py:3: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  weights_np=np.array(weights)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1456, in BaseResourceVariable.__float__(self)
   1455 def __float__(self):
-> 1456   return float(self.value().numpy())

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [42], line 5
      3 weights_np=np.array(weights)
      4 print(type(weights_np))
----> 5 weights_npf=np.float32(weights_np)
      6 print(weights_np.size)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I want to convert these weights into 1D array, i.e., a row vector. I have used np.flatten, np.ravel, np.reshape but am not able to get the required output. For all the np methods described, the shape of the weights and type remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.weights` will give you a list of the weights tensors.
If you want to covert them to `numpy` I would suggest to use list comprehension:

```
weights=model.weights    
weights_np = [i.numpy() for i in weights]
```

If you want to convert all of these to a 1D array one way to do is with `.flatten()`, then you could concatenate them if that is what you want.

```
flatten_w = [i.flatten() for i in weights_np]
np.concatenate(flatten_w)
```

You could do it in one step as well

```
flatten_w = [i.numpy().flatten() for i in weights]
```

Also if you want to change the type use `.astype(np.float32)`